# Rotate div on an anchor point?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to rotate a DIV 80x120px (a playing card) by a set angle. But it has to rotate relative to its bottom-right corner and not it's center point.

[Example of what I'm trying to create](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3894792/screenshot.png)

I want to create a fan of cards but they have to be rotated each for 0.5 degree. I've found some rotating examples but they don't include the bottom-right corner based rotation, only center based rotation.

Is there a way to achieve this? I think jQuery is the answer but haven't found any solution yet.

Comment: The link is dead, please fix the link. Also use Stack Overflows image upload (Ctrl-G), NOT Dropbox!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on browsers that you want to support and the way you are rotating the DIV

Latest browsers support the `-vendor-transform-origin:` CSS3 property which does exactly what you are looking for.